# Radio button group in MobileFirst Android

Tags: android, radio-button

I want to put two radio buttons (male and female) in my application.

I did so using radio buttons (not group) but the problem is: 
a button can not be unchecked also both can be checked at the same time

RadioButton group is a group of three buttons and I only need two. Is there a way they can be two?

So any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Male"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Female"/>
        </RadioGroup>
```